# Error trying to overlay and remove elements with removeChild

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, button, removechild

i have a problem in the following code snippet.

```
for (var i=0;i<data.parlist.length;i++){
            var inp = document.createElement("input")
            var label = document.createElement("label")
            var labelValue = document.createElement("label")
            var subDiv = document.createElement("div")
            var br = document.createElement("br")
            try{
                var dBtn = document.getElementById(data.parlist[i].id);
                var dLabel = document.getElementById(data.parlist[i].id + " label")
                
                var dDiv = document.getElementById(data.parlist[i].id +" div");

                var inprad = document.getElementById(data.parlist[i].id+" inp_rad");
                var dLabelRad = document.getElementById(data.parlist[i].id + " label_rad")

                var dSubDiv = document.getElementById(data.parlist[i].id +" div_rad");

                dSubDiv.replaceChild(inprad);
                dSubDiv.removeChild(dLabelRad);

                dDiv.removeChild(dSubDiv);
                
                dDiv.removeChild(dBtn);
                dDiv.removeChild(dLabel);
                
                myDiv.removeChild(dDiv);
                
            }catch{
                console.log("no")
            }
```

This for loop is inside a function that when clicking on a button of a station shows the parameters.in this way:

[image]

[image: Shows station parameters]

What you see in the images works, but the problem that I have come to `try` to clarify is that when I press the button for example as **station 1** appears in the image and then I press the button for example of **station 2** the try that is supposed to you must remove the previous parameters with `removeChild` does not work, the parameters of **station 1** remain in the div and the parameters of **station 2** are added below these instead of being removed

[image: Shows how the parameters are added below the other parameters]

Within the `try` there is a problem but I do not know what it is, I say this because when I check the page and open the **console** I get the message that I left in the `catch` a "no"

[image: The "no" on the console]

Thanks for reading my problem and any suggestions are welcome as I am desperate to find a solution.

Comment: Change your catch to `catch (e) { console.log(e) }` and check the console.

Comment: You are missing semi-colons.

Comment: this is the error that appears in `catch`, several times: `TypeError: dSubDiv is null
    parlist http://localhost/js/sConnetion.js:94
    jQuery 8
    parlist http://localhost/js/sConnetion.js:63
    onclick http://localhost/js/sConnetion.js:49
    EventHandlerNonNull* http://localhost/js/sConnetion.js:47
    jQuery 8
    <anonymous> http://localhost/js/sConnetion.js:37`

Comment: now this `TypeError: Node.removeChild: Argument 1 is not an object.`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass 2 inputs to the `replaceChild` function.

```
parentNode.replaceChild(newChild, oldChild);
```

### For more info refer [Mozilla docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild).

Here is some additional advice

1. When you log for debugging, use some meaningful messages. In your case you could do

```
try {
 ...
} catch (err) {
   console.log(err);
}
```

2. From the questions nothing is clear about what is there in `data.parlist` and whether that is implemented properly.